# How to detect a line break next to some string and remove it?

Tags: php

I have the `description` column in database and it contains the  sample data as bleow

```
Product/Service: product
First Payment Amount: $50 USD
Recurring Amount: $10 USD
```

I want to replace the string `First Payment Amount: $50 USD` with `blank` so i used `str_replace` as below

```
$details = str_replace('First Payment Amount: $50 USD', '', $description);
echo $detsils;
```

but the result shows like this

```
Product/Service: product

Recurring Amount: $10 USD
```

there is a gap. it is because of the line break after the string `First Payment Amount: $50 USD`. how to detect the `line breaks` next to some string and remove it in such cases and get the result like this.

```
Product/Service: product 
Recurring Amount: $10 USD
```

Comment: You store that in array or in single string?

Comment: How about: `$details = str_replace('\nFirst Payment Amount: $50 USD', '', $description);`?

Comment: hi `yergo`,its a single string and  i'm uing `ckeditor` to store the text for the `description` column

Comment: hi `Marc`, `$details = str_replace('\nFirst Payment Amount: $50 USD', '', $description);` not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` to work it at one catch:

```
$url = "Product/Service: product
First Payment Amount: $50 USD
Recurring Amount: $10 USD";

$url = preg_replace('/First Payment Amount\: \$[0-9]+ USD[\s]+/i', '', $url);
```

`\s` [(docs here)](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is searching for whitespaces, newlines of both kind are whitespaces, so you dont mind operating system youre receiving strings from.

`i` at the end is not required, but I'm used to it. It turns patterns to match case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
$details = str_replace('First Payment Amount: $50 USD\r\n', '', $details);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one after str replace

```
$details =  preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $description );
```